# Выделить область на графике ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

У меня есть некий график с точками, который формируется, например, так:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = rnorm(1000)
y = rnorm(1000)
dt = data.frame(x, y)
g <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y))
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + theme_bw() + xlab("x") + ylab("y") + xlim(-2.5, 2.5) + ylim(-2.5, 2.5)
g <- g + geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0.5, colour = "red")
g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept = 1, colour = "red") + geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "red")
plot(g)
```

Я хочу на полученном графике выделить следующую область, как показано на рисунке (сейчас просто покрасил в Paint'е)

[image: Пример графика]

Пробовал использовать функцию `geom_polygon()`, но не могу понять, какие параметры в неё передавать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение с помощью применения функции `geom_ribbon()`. Как я понял из описания, для каждого `x` функция отражает интервал определяемый аргументами `ymin`, `ymax`.

Область ограничена тремя функциями: `x = 1, y = 0, y = 0.5x`. Сформируем соответствующие координаты:

```
# Формируем координаты x
xr <- c(1, 2.5)
# Формируем ymin, ymax
yrmin <- c(0, 0)
yrmax <- 0.5 * xr
# Создадим датафрейм (необходим для функции geom_ribbon)
dt2 <- data.frame(x = xr, y = yrmax)

# Добавим к графику geom_ribbon
g <- g + geom_ribbon(data = dt2, aes(x = xr, ymin = yrmin, ymax = yrmax), fill = "green", alpha = 0.4)
```

Получим следующий график:

[image: График]